# Footer not auto moving down the page

Tags: html, css

i am using this CSS for my footer:

```
/* FOOTER */
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:580px;
    border-top:4px solid #666666;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
#footer-inner {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    height:inherit;
}
#footerTop {
    width:100%;
    height:480px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom:2px #000000 solid;
}
#footerTopLeft {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
#footerTopMid {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
#footerTopRight {
    width:30%;
    height:420px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 15px 10px 15px;
}

#enquiryForm                    { clear:both; padding:8px 40px 0 0;  }
.enquiryField                   { clear:both; padding:5px 0; }
.enquiryField label             { clear:none; float:left; }
.enquiryField input             { clear:none; font-family:Calibri; float:right; padding:3px; width:189px; }
.enquiryField textarea          { clear:none; float:right; font-family:Calibri; padding:5px; width:189px; }

.enquiryError                   { clear:both; color:#fff; font-family:Calibri; }
#enquirySent                    { color:#fff; font-family:Calibri; }
```

but it is not moving down the page automatically depending on how much content is above it. here is a fiddle with the full css/HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctmGT/

i seem to have to change the  div height that i have depending on the amount of content i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change

```
<div style="clear: both; height:500px;"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="push"></div>
```